# Lower Bound of a Function for proving an Inequality

Tags: functions, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

Actually, I am trying to solve a mathematical problem, which involves proving an inequality. For that I already know the bounds of LHS of the inequality and now I need the lower bound of the RHS of the inequality (which I mentioned below in the list).

I want a function $F(x)$ such that $F(x) \leq G(x)$, where $G(x)$ is:

1. $\sqrt{x}  \ln(x)  \ln(x)$
2. $\frac{1}{8}\pi  \sqrt{x}  \ln(x)  \ln(x)$
3. $2  \sqrt{x}  \ln(x)  \ln(x)$

Here all the above three values are equivalent (in the context of the question) so all or any value that is suitable can be considered for the calculation of lower bound.

But the additional constraint or condition is that $F(x) > H(x)$,

where $H(x) = 0.006409\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$

**Note -** Kindly note that this is NOT a homework question. I have been trying very hard to find it, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just take $F=G$? (That said, anyway, for each of your 3 cases for $G$, you will have to restrict the domain to $x$ large enough, so that $H(x)< G(x)$.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes that might work. But $H(x)$ is actually the upper bound of another function. My approach of proving the inequality is that if we have bounds for both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and the upper bound of $f(x)$ is less than lower bound of $g(x)$ for all $x > n$ then also we can conclude that $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x > n$. So will it work if I take $F = G$ here? Anyways, I understood what logic you applied, so thanks.

Comment: You need the inequlity to hold in all $\mathbb{R}^+$? Because taking $F=G$ you obtain that the inequlity is true for $0<x<1$ and $1.22 \le x\le 2 \cdot 10^{13}$ (see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=when+%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D+%28%5Clog%28x%29%29%5E2-0.006409%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B%5Cln%28x%29%7D%3E0) ) $\quad$ also: do you need $F$ to be continuos or having some regularity?

Comment: Yes @Marco. Thanks a lot for pointing that out! I want the inequality to hold true for all positive values of x and that's probably why we can't set F = G. Also, as of now, I don't think there's any requirements for F except the ones mentioned in question. Please help me if you can.

Comment: "that's probably why we can't set F = G. ": No. The inequality holds true for some $F$ if and only if it holds for $F=G$, i.e. iff $H<G$. Note that $H(x)<G(x)$ for every $x\in(0,1)$, and for every $x$ large enough.

Comment: @AnneBauval Maybe you meant for every $x$ small enough? For big $x$ $$\sqrt{x}\log^2(x)< \frac{x}{\log(x)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Marco and Anne Bauval too

Comment: @Marco, oops yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function that satisfies both the inequality for all the value of $\mathbb{R}^+$ as, for big $x$ you will need
$$
O\left(\frac{x}{\log(x)}\right) <F(x) < O \left(\sqrt{x} (\log(x))^2\right)
$$
that is absurd. Similarly for $x= 1+\epsilon$ you will need

$$
\frac{1+\epsilon}{\log(1+\epsilon)}< F(1+\epsilon)< (\sqrt{1+\epsilon} (\log(1+\epsilon))^2)
$$
Taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0^+$ you will reach an absurd.